# imutils.resize will not get the right shape: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (91, 64, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In my model file I have already set the inputshape to (64,64,3) width=64, height=64, and 3 channels but when I executed the file I got an error expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (91, 64, 3) as shown below. What does (91, 64, 3) means and why did I get that error? How can I fix it? Please help

the error I got

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (91, 64, 3)
```

lenet.py

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense, Flatten
from keras import backend as K


class LeNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        #initialize the model
        model = Sequential()
        inputShpage = (height, width, depth)

        # if we are using "channel first" update the input shape
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShpage = (depth, height, width)

        # first set of CONV => RELU => MaxPooling
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=inputShpage))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # second set of CONV => RELU => MaxPooling
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # FC => RELU layer
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(500))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # softmax classifier for probability
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

model.py

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.utils import np_utils
from lenet import LeNet
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the argument
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to the dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to the output model or saved model")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the list of data and label
data = []
labels = []

for imagePath in sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))):
    # load the image, preprocessing it and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=64)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    # extract the class label from the image path and update the labels list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-3]
    label = "Hong" if label == "hong" else "Not Hong"
    labels.append(label)

    # scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0,1]
    data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
    label = np.array(labels)

    # convert labels from integers to vectors
    le = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
    labels = np_utils.to_categorical(le.transform(labels), 2)

    # account for skew in the labeled data
    classTotals = labels.sum(axis=0)
    classWeight = classTotals.max() / classTotals

    # split the data into training_set and test_set
    (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels, 
                                                    test_size=0.33, 
                                                    random_state=42)

    # initialize the model
    print("[ WORKING ON MODEL ] compiling model.....")
    model = LeNet.build(width=64, height=64, depth=3, classes=2)
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

    # train the network
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] traning the network.....")
    H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
                class_weight=classWeight, batch_size=32, epochs=25, verbose=1)

    # evaluate the network
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] evaluating the network.....")
    predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
    print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1),
                                target_names=le.classes_))

    # saving the model
    print("[ WORKING ON NETWORK ] serializing network.....")
    model.save(args["model"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imutils.resize()` keeps the aspect ratio of a picture, so you will only be able to specify *either* width *or* height, but not both. Since you may need to change the aspect ratio to make it fit into your neural network, I suggest you use `cv2.resize()`.

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
```

instead of this:

```
image = imutils.resize(image, width=64)
```

Comment: I did what you said but still getting the same error

Comment: whats the shape of `data` before you pass it to the network?

Comment: did you re-run the entire thing from the start after implementing my changes? it's hard to ebelieve that it didn't work

Comment: Do you mean the images shape? all images have different shape like some got 130x160 and some got 134x170 something like that?

Comment: you need to make sure that in `model.fit(trainX, trainY...`, `trainX` NEEDS to be `(64, 64, 3)`

Comment: So you mean i have to set all the images in the dataset to 64x64?

Comment: yes. if you implemented my suggestion, all pictures should be automatically resized. did you run the whole thing again? if you're running from the command line, did you save the py file?

Comment: Yes, I did save and also tried to run that command again but still getting same error

Comment: can you print the shape of trainX and testX

Comment: Hi sir! it works now and you are right the problem is about the shape. I just searched  on google and it showed that imutils.resize() function resize only the width so I changed it to ```cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))``` and now it works but I just got another problem haha. The problem is ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment```.

Comment: I can't say. I don't see where 'batch_index' is in your code. But that's another problem. I'll update my answer in light of your solution

Comment: Thanks you so much sir!

Comment: I have done it. i think it will be more helpful now

Comment: If you think my edited answer can help future users you can mark it as accepted, or suggest improvements if you want

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: i suggested cv2 instead of imutils. because imutils keeps the image ratio